# CollectionType with mixed entry_type

Tags: php, arrays, forms, symfony, arraycollection

In Symfony 3 / PHP 7, I need a form who accept an array of mixed type (string, int and array). "entry_type" param for CollectionType only accept a unique Type. How can I have a mixed type ?

```php
$builder
     ->add('value', CollectionType::class, array(
         'entry_type' => ?,
         'allow_add' => true,
         'allow_delete' => true,
     ));
```

Comment: You can use a simple TextType, but ... How your user will enter an array in your collection? Probably you should use a transform ...

Comment: User send me an array from frontend with "random" key/value. Any exemple of a transform who help me ?

Comment: How he/she send it? A "random" key/value in a html text input element? An transformer example is this https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use embed forms. In your custom form type you can define multiple input fields for your need and than use it in your CollectionType.

```
// src/Form/TagType.php
namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Tag;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class TagType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('string_field')
            ->add('int_field')
            ->add('whatever_field');
    }
}
```

Use in as entry_type like this:

```
 use App\Form\TagType;

 // ...
 $builder
      ->add('multiple_fields_collection', CollectionType::class, [
          'entry_type' => TagType::class,
          'allow_add' => true,
          'allow_delete' => true,
      ]);
```

More information:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

Comment: Thank's for the reply. I can't used a form with defined field because I do not know what will be in this array.

Comment: I think you confuse what 'entry_type' option does. It doesn`t define how data will be transformed. It define a class that describe how the value should be threated and what should be rendered.

For your needs you only want one TextType and transformation should be done by yourself in controller or encapsulated in your own class. But this is not job for a Symfony or Symfony forms.

 $builder->add('field', TextType::class)